# Error spc0224: Module GeneXusUnanimo not available for .NET Web environment al instalar Genexus 18

Tags: genexus

Estoy instalando Genexus 18. Al seguir las instrucciones del manual para crear la primera aplicación, me aparece el error que muestro a continuación:

> error spc0224: Module GeneXusUnanimo not available for .NET Web environment. (Web Panel 'General.UI.MasterUnanimoSidebar', Details)
> error spc0224: Module GeneXusUnanimo not available for .NET Web environment. (Data Provider 'General.UI.SidebarItemsDP', Details)
> error spc0224: Module GeneXus not available for .NET Web environment. (Web Panel 'General.UI.MasterUnanimoSidebar', Details)
> Failed: Specification
> Failed: Run Developer Menu

Answer (score 0):

te estaria faltando hacer update del Modulo Unanimo. Par hacerlo, tenes que ir a:

Knowledge Manager > Manage Module References

y hacer Update/Restore del módulo GeneXusUnanimo.